# Нужна ли запятая перед "участниками"?

Tags: пунктуация

Имеется следующий текст:

> закрыт по причине того, что не соответствует тематике сайта участниками...

Нужна ли запятая перед словом "участниками"?

На месте многоточия будет перечисление имен конкретных участников.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь нужна не только запятая (закрыть оборот), а и тире, иначе добавляемое дополнение (закрыт кем) будет недопустимым образом оторвано от основного предложения; это тире нужно для замещения подразумеваемого "он закрыт" или "закрыт он" (перед таким "освежающим" добавлением была бы точка с запятой, если не точка):

> (Вопрос) закрыт по причине того, что не соответствует тематике сайта, -
>
> участниками...

Возможно даже оформление вставки (ещё одно тире после "закрыт" - это сделает акцент на "кем закрыт" и отодвинет на второй план причину), но это не обязательно - ввиду имеющейся тесной связи "слева". Либо можно заключить в скобки "участниками..." - тогда запятая не нужна (после скобок будет точка).

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна, потому что придаточное предложение должно быть обособлено.

Но формулировка, на мой взгляд, не лучшая. Может, попробовать переформулировать: *Закрыт участниками <...>, так как не соответствует тематике сайта*?

Comment: Переформулировать можно, но мне кажется это приведет к смещению акцента с причины на участников. Или Вы так не считаете? Общую фразу можно посмотреть [тут](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3952/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5).

Comment: @alexolut да, кажется, что приведет. Если важно вынести причину на первый план: *Вопрос закрыт, так как не соответствует тематике сайта,(-) участниками*.

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать короче и без запятой: **Вопрос закрыт по причине несоответствия тематике сайта участниками....**

Answer (score 0):

Я бы тоже просто поменяла порядок слов в предложении. Вопрос закрыт участниками, так как не соответствует тематике сайта. Допустим и другой вариант.  Вопрос закрыли участники как не соответствующий  тематике сайта. По-моему, акценты не смещаются.